# GridView setOnItemClickListener don't work

Tags: java, android, gridview

Am trying to get my `setOnItemClickListener` working, but I can not get it to work. I am newbie android developer.

`LocationGalleryActivity.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationGalleryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
    private Vector<PhotoModel> vphotos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_gallery);

        //Conectamos a la base de datos
        LocationsSQLite dbloc = new LocationsSQLite(this, "DBLocations.db",
                null, 1);
        //Obtenemos el vector de imagenes
        vphotos = dbloc.getPhotos();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid_image,
                getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                    Log.i("GridView", "Se ha pulsado");
                 /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                         "content://media/internal/images/media")); 
                         startActivity(intent); */
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + "#Selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Obtenemos las imagenes para mostrar en el GridLayout
     * 
     * @return Array de ImageItems (Imagene y su nombre)
     */
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
        // Vamos obteniendo las imagenes del array
        for (int i = 0; i < vphotos.size(); i++) {
            PhotoModel p = vphotos.get(i);
            //Obtenemos la miniatura de la imagen
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p.getPath()
                    + ".thumbnails/" + p.getName());
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, p.getName()));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_location_gallery.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GridViewAdapter.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

row_grid_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

brought with it a while and can not get it to work.

Comment: Cannot get to work isn't very descriptive, and there's a lot of code there...

Comment: Have you tried moving android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to GridView?

Comment: What strikes me is that clicking on an item in the GridView is not the action described in the onItemClick method is performed. I am Spanish and I do not write very well in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved changing on row_click_image.xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

to:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove android:clickable="true" from your LinearLayout in row_grid_image.xml

Comment: It does not work, I removed android: clickable = "true" and nothing